# Partial fractions in Laplace Transform

Tags: laplace-transform, partial-fractions

Solve:

$$y''+y'+\frac{5}{4}=U_\frac{\pi}{2}(t)f(t-\frac{\pi}{2})$$

becomes:

$$[s^2+s+\frac{5}{4}]Y(s)=\frac{1-e^\frac{-\pi*s}{2}}{s^2}$$

becomes:

$$Y(s)=\frac{1-e^\frac{-\pi*s}{2}}{s^2[(s+\frac{1}{2})^2+1]}$$

and now I am having trouble using the method of partial fractions to move forward. Can anyone help me a bit?  I can finish the problem, so I do not need anyone to solve this completely (feel free if you just enjoy solving these types of problems).

The method a friend showed split ^^ that into two and then solved for the $\frac{1}{blah}$ portion. He called this $H(s)$ and then said $Y(s)=H(s)-e^\frac{-\pi*s}{2}H(s)$ and then he finds the inverse Laplace transforms. So maybe I should only decompose the 1/stuff part of that?  Any ideas?

Comment: What is $f(t-\pi/2)$?

Comment: Part of the Heaviside function. If you consider the step function $U_c(T)$ then $U_c(T)F(t-c)$ is the same step function translated in the positive t direction by c units.

Comment: amozti - forgot to tag you in the above post. Hope that helps.